# Holomorphic map proper after shrinking (from J. Kollar's Lecture on Resolution of Singularities)

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-geometry

I'm currently reading Janos Kollar's Lecture on Resolution of Singularities and have some problems to understand a detail in the proof on page 10 of

> **Thm 1.5** $ \ $(Riemann) $ \ $ Let $F(x,y)$ be an irreducible complex polynomial and $C:=V(F(x,y)) \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ the corresponding compex curve. Then there is a $1$-dimensional complex manifold $\bar{C}$ and a proper holomorphic map $\sigma: \bar{C} \to C$ which is a biholomorphism except at finitely many points.
>
> Proof. Since $F$ irreducible and $\partial F / \partial y$ have only finitely many common points $\Sigma \subset C$. By implicit function thoerem,  the first coordinate projection $\pi: C \to \mathbb{C}$ is a local analytic biholomorphism on $C \backslash \Sigma$.
>
> We start by constructing a resolution for a small neighborhood of a point $p \in \Sigma$. For notational convenience assume $p=0$, the orgin. Let $B_{\epsilon} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ denote the ball of radius $\epsilon$ around the origin. Chossing $\epsilon$ small enough, we may assume that $C \cap \{y=0\} \cap B_{\epsilon}= \{0\}$.
>
> Next, by choosing $\eta$ small enough, we can also assume that the restricted map

$$\pi: C \cap B_{\epsilon} \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_{\eta}) \to \Delta_{\eta}$$

> is **proper** (???) and a local analytic biholomorphism exept at the origin, where $\Delta_{\eta} \subset \mathbb{C}$ is the disc of radius $\eta$ ...

Question: Why shrinking $\eta$ small enough makes the restriction of $\pi$ to $C \cap B_{\epsilon} \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_{\eta})$ a proper map (from topological viewpoint)?

In topology $\pi$ is proper if for every compact $K$ set the preimage $\pi^{-1}(K)$ is also compact.

Comment: Hint: $\pi$ is the restriction of the continuous map between compacts $\pi: cl(C\cap B_\epsilon \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_\eta))\to cl(\Delta_\eta)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan:by $cl(-)$ you mean the closure, right? If that's true, then under the restricted map $\pi: cl(C\cap B_\epsilon \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_\eta))\to cl(\Delta_\eta)$ the subset $cl(C\cap B_\epsilon \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_\eta)) \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ is closed and bounded, thus compact. The point is why in the whole story it's neccessary to "shrink" the disc $\Delta_{\eta}$ small enough to obtain properness of $\pi: C \cap B_{\epsilon} \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_{\eta}) \to \Delta_{\eta}$?

Comment: I not see from your hint where the "shrink small enough"-condition comes into the game. Respectively, which pathology could happen if we choose $\eta$ "not small enough"?

Comment: UP to a biholomorphism your $\pi$ behaves like $z\to z^n$ which is a local biholomorphism $0<|z|<1\to 0<|z|<1$

Comment: @reuns:I don't think that it's true. That would be true if $C$ is smooth in $p=0$, in other words a Riemann surface. In the case of a holomorphic map between RS you are right: the all look locally like $z \mapsto z^n$ as you said. In our case $C$ has a *singularity* in $p$ and thus I'm not sure why $\pi$ should locally behave like $z \mapsto z^n$.

Comment: Ok but it is true. Because the map is meromorphic from the underlying compact Riemann surface $X$ to the Riemann sphere. The set of smooth points of your curve corresponds to $X$ minus finitely many points.

Comment: by "underlying compact Riemann surface" you mean $C \backslash \Sigma$? i.e. after removing all singularities?

Comment: and then you apply Riemann extension thm?

Comment: @reuns: yes, I see you are right with statement on the local shape of $\pi$. Ok thus we are now in following setting (after appropriate binolomorphic transformation): Let $\pi: \Delta_{\eta} \to \Delta_{\eta}, z \mapsto z^n$ with $\Delta_{\eta}= \{z \in \mathbb{C} \ \vert \ \vert z \vert < \eta \}$. Why is this $\pi$ proper? Is it obvious?

Comment: If we cosider instead of open $\Delta_{\eta}$ it's closure $\overline{\Delta_{\eta}}$ then it's clear as $\overline{\Delta_{\eta}}$ is closed & bounded, thus compact. But in this case the autor would impose already the restriction $\pi: C \cap B_{\epsilon} \to \mathbb{C}$ instead of more shrinked $\pi: C \cap B_{\epsilon} \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_{\eta}) \to \Delta_{\eta}$, since $C \cap B_{\epsilon} $ is closed and bonded, thus compact. That is I asume that by $\Delta_{\eta}$ Kollar means the open disc but in this case I not see why $\pi: \Delta_{\eta} \to \Delta_{\eta}, z \mapsto z^n$ is closed.

Comment: It doesn't work in higher dimension but for a finite extension $K/\Bbb{C}(z)$ there is a unique (compact) Riemann surface $X$ such that $K$ is the field of meromorphic functions $X\to \Bbb{C}$. By the primitive element theorem $K=\Bbb{C}(z)[x]/(f(z,x))$ with $f\in \Bbb{C}[z,x]$, the set of $(z,x)$ such that $|\partial_xf(z,x)|+|\partial_zf(z,x)|\ne 0$ is  $X$ minus finitely many points, those finitely many points are the discrete valuations at each singular point plus the discrete valuations at each point at $\infty$. $X$ is the set of discrete valuations of $K$.

Comment: let me resume: as you said $\pi: C \cap B_{\epsilon} \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_{\eta}) \backslash \{p\} \to \Delta_{\eta} \backslash \{0\}$ look locally indeed like $z \mapsto z^n$ between zwo holed unit discs $0<|z|<1\to 0<|z|<1$. Meanwhile I know that it's proper. Ok, now the question is what happens if we add $p$ to $C \cap B_{\epsilon} \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_{\eta}) \backslash \{p\}$ resp $0$ to $\Delta_{\eta} \backslash \{0\}$. Obviously $C \cap B_{\epsilon} \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_{\eta})$ is not homeomorphic to disc $0 \le \vert z \vert <1$ but

Comment: to the glued $(C \cap B_{\epsilon} \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_{\eta})) \coprod (0<|z|<1)$ via identification $C \cap B_{\epsilon} \cap \pi^{-1}(\Delta_{\eta}) \backslash \{p\} \cong (0<|z|<1)$. Does the extension preserve the properness?