# Polynomial map proper

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $n \ge 1$ an integer. We consider the polynomial map $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}, z \mapsto z^n$.

Questions:

I) is this map $f$ proper for every $n$ (in topological sense) and why?

II) Let $r >0$ arbitrary positive real number. Consider the *open* disc (=open 1D ball) $B_r(0)$ with radius $r$ abound $0$.

Is the restricted map $f: B_r(0) \to B_{r^n}(0), z \mapsto z^n$ proper?

Attention: we consider restriction of $f$ between *open* discs; for their closures the question is trivial since the closures are compact.

Recall: In topology $f$ is called proper if for every compact $K$ set the preimage $f^{-1}(K)$ is also compact.

EDIT #1/ideas: I know a criterion that says that a map is proper if it is closed & it's fibers are compact. What do we know about $f$? The fibers are obviously finite (= zeros of $z^n-a$) and thus compact. I don't know if $f$ is closed. Since we are working with complex numbers $f$ is definitely surjective in I) as well in II) by choice of radius. Does it help? Possibly there is another strategy to show properness.

EDIT#2: Assume we know I) is true (polynomial maps are closed & fibrs finite thus proper. Can we conclude for this that II) is also proper? The main obstruction I see is that the (open) inclusion of the disc $B_r(0) \subset \mathbb{C}$ is obviuosly not proper. Thus a composition argument fails.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins: See my EDIT

Comment: Polynomials are closed IIRC.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Is there a standard argument?

Comment: @TimGrosskreutz no, just something I recall. No proof in my head.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Ok, if we assume that we know it, then $f$ in I) is closed & has compact fibers and thus is proper. Can we conclude from this that the restriction of $f$ to open disc as in II) is also proper? I don't know why. The open embedding $B_r(0) \subset \mathbb{C}$ isn't proper, thus I not see how we can derive properness in II) from that one in I). Do you see an argument?

Comment: (nonconstant) polynomial preimage of a bounded set is bounded since $|p(z)| \to \infty$ when $|z| \to \infty$. This obviously implies properness as the preimage of a closed set is closed by continuity. Note that if we restrict to an open set $D$,  $p(D)$ is open but it can happen that $p(\partial D)$ has elements in $p(D)$ so there may be compact sets in $p(D)$ with preimages that have noncompact components - that doesn't happen in the OP example $z^n$ on the $r$ disc but but it can happen if you shift the disc to have $1$ inside and a root of unity of order $n$ on the boundary

Comment: @Conrad: So I) is true. What about the restricted case II). I don't see a way to conclude the properness from case I). You lost also a remark on openess of polynomial maps. Can it help here? In EDIT \#2 I explained the obstruction which I see that cause cruical problem to use I)

Comment: I not see how it can be concluded from your argument on global case I)

Comment: A set in the plane is compact iff it is closed and bounded so the preimage of a compact set is closed (continuity) and bounded by the argument given, hence it is compact. For open sets, the issue is that boundary points can go inside - easy example is $z(z-1)$ on the open unit disc and take the preimage of a small closed disc around zero which will have two components, a small compact domain around zero but also the intersection of such around $1$ with the disc and that is not compact since it is only relatively closed. It's easy to show that is the only obstruction, so it depends on situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments got too long, I will make them in an answer. Let $P$ a nonconstant polynomial in the plane. Then:

1: $P$ is proper as a map $P:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$

2: If we restrict $P$ to a domain $D$ and $\Omega=P(D)$ is the image domain ($P$ is an open map being analytic nonconstant so  $\Omega$ is open, while it is connected by continuity), then $P$ is proper as a map $P: D \to \Omega$ if and only if $P(\partial D) \cap \Omega =\emptyset$

Proof: $|P(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$ hence the preimage of bounded sets by $P$ is bounded. But in the plane, $K$ compact iff $K$ is bounded and closed and obviously $P^{-1}(K)$ is then bounded by the above argument and closed by continuity, hence it is compact, hence $P$ is proper as a plane map.

For 2, we notice that if $K \subset \Omega$, $K$ compact, then $P^{-1}(K) \cap D=L$ is bounded since $P^{-1}(K)$ is so, but  $L$ is only relatively closed in $D$. However if $P(\partial D) \cap \Omega =\emptyset$ and $x_n \in L, x_n \to x$, $P(x_n) \to P(x) \in K$ so $x \in \bar D, P(x) \in \Omega$. As $\bar D = D \cup \partial D$ and we cannot have $x \in \partial D$ by hypothesis, it follows $x \in D$, hence $x \in L$, hence $L$ closed, so compact.

Conversely, if $P$ restricted to $D$ is proper and $x \in \partial D, P(x)=y \in \Omega$, then $P(z)=(z-x)^nQ(z)+y, n \ge 1, Q(x) \ne 0$ hence the preimage of a small closed disc centered at $y$ and included in $\Omega$ has a component that is a a compact neighborhood of $x$ in the plane, hence its intersection with $D$ is not compact which contradicts the fact that $P$ is proper restricted to $D$.

A simple example to show that this happens is $P(z)=z(z-1)$ on the open unit disc. Clearly $0 \in P(D)$ but a small closed disc centered at zero has as preimage in the open disc, two components, one around zero compact, but one that is the intersection of a compact neighborhood of $1$ with the open unit disc, hence non-compact.

In the examples of the OP, $z \to z^n$ on the discs centered at the origin, obviously the boundary condition is satisfied, so the maps are proper when restricted too, but if we shift the domain to a disc containing $1$ but having another root of unit of order $n$ on the boundary, the restricted maps are not proper any more

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer, that was exactly what I was looking for! One remark: Can the argumentation you used above tranfered to following problem: Let $P: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function, e.g. $P \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,..., x_n]$ a polynomial. Assume That $D \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is a *bounded*, but not neccessary open or closed set, $\Omega:=P(D)$ is also bounded. Assume, that $P(\partial D) \cap \Omega =\emptyset$. Is then the restriction $P:D \to \Omega$ proper?

Comment: Previously, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3551911/holomorphic-map-proper-after-shrinking-from-j-kollars-lecture-on-resolution-o was exactly the motivation of this question and going through your arguments it seems that the arguments can be extended to the problem im my last comment above. Or do I oversee a detail?

Comment: first I am not sure what the condition mentioned means if $D$ is not open, as $\partial D$ may have points in $D$  - if $D$ is open, the same argument applies since the only thing you need to prove is $P^{-1}{K} \cap D=L$ is closed (since it is bounded as $D$ is so and relatively closed, but the condition on the boundary guarantees that $x_n \in L, x_n \to x$ implies $x \in D$ hence in $L$, hence $L$ closed

Comment: I understand the point now about $D$ not open, in the example mentioned, though it would be open in lower dimensions so to speak - the point is that you need some regularity on the domain

Comment: could you loose few words on what you mean by "some regularity on the domain"?

Comment: the set you want to have this property needs to be generally nice - in the example linked it is isomorphic with a small disc, where the behavior at the origin of the map in question is more complicated, but the behaviour on the punctured disc is very nice (conformal); so you can definitely use simple arguments as above; the problem comes if the set in question is weird (eg clusters badly)